# Python-binance api Twap order

Tags: python, binance-api-client

I have been exploring Algorithm trading with little background in programming.

I have a script that trades on Binance and I noticed the Twap API that was released for futures trading. https://www.binance.com/en/support/faq/093927599fd54fd48857237f6ebec0b0

I am trying to incorporate this into my existing code, but I can't seem to figure this out.

A simple market order will be

```
client.futures_create_order(
                symbol='BTCUSDT',
                type="MARKET",
                side="BUY",  
                quantity=0.2 
                )
```

How do I create a TWAP order? I have tried setting "type" to "Twap" and added mandatory parameters but I get APIError(code=-1116): Invalid orderType.

Answer (score 0):

For placing Twap futures order, you may wish to send request to this endpoint:

`POST /sapi/v1/algo/futures/newOrderTwap`

I think the method you are using is for placing normal order, which is calling the endpoint `POST /fapi/v1/order`

The document: https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#time-weighted-average-price-twap-new-order-trade